# C#: Get Feedback from SqlConnection Object?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently facing an issue where it takes quite a while to process information from a server, and I would like to provide active feedback for the user to know what is going on while the application appears to be just sitting around.

A little about the application: it allows the user to pull all databases from a specified server along with all content within those databases. This can take quite a while sometimes, since some of our databases can reach 2TB in size. Each server can contain hundreds of databases and so as a result, if I try to load a server with 100 databases, and 30% of those databases are over 100GB in size, it takes a good couple of minutes before the application is able to run effectively again.

Currently I just have a simple loading message that says: "Please wait, this could take a while...". However, in my opinion, this is not really sufficient for something that can take a few minutes.

So as a result, I am wondering if there is a way to track the progress of the `SqlConnection` object as it is executing the specified query? If so, what kind of details would I be able to provide and are there any readily available resources to look over and better understand the solution?

I am hopeful that there is a way to do this without having to recreate the `SqlConnection` object altogether.

Thank you all for your help!

**EDIT**

Also, as another note; I am NOT looking for handouts of code here. I am looking for resources that will help me in this situation if any are available. I have been looking into this issue for a few days already, I figure the best place to ask for help is here at this point.

**Extra**

A more thorough explanation: I am wondering if there is a way to provide the user with names of databases, tables, views, etc that are currently being received.

For example:

- Loading Table X From Database Y On Server Z
- Loading Table A From Database B On Server Z

Comment: Just an idea here.  Have your code kick off a SPROC that immediately returns after kicking off a SQL job.  The sproc should return a GUID that identifies the users job, so the user can query for status.  The job can write progress records to a table, which you can query.  The connection does not need to remain open, the users application does not need to remain open.  It's all disconnected.  The GUID would be used to retrieve info about the job and optionally control the job.

Comment: You could break down the query into smaller ones and report back to the UI once each stage is finished.

Comment: See, this is why I ask questions on StackOverflow when I'm stuck. However, what would be the performance trade off? Is this going to slow the processing down significantly? I could easily pull a list of database names before loading details of each database and loop through that list to provide feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SqlConnection has an InfoMessage-Event to which you can assign a method.
Furthermore you have to set the FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors-Property to true.
No you can do something like

```
private void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < e.Errors.Count; index++)
        {
            var message = e.Errors[index];
            //use the message object
        }
    }
```

Note that you should only evaluate messages with an errorcode lower then 11 (everything above is a 'real' error).

Depending on what command you are using sometime the server already generates such info messages (for example at VERIFY BACKUP).

Anyways you can also use this to report progress form a stored procedure or a query.

Pseudocode (im not an sqlguy):

```
RAISEERROR('START', 1,1) WITH NOWAIT; -- Will raise your OnInfoMessage-method 
WHILE
-- Execute something
RAISEERROR('Done something', 1,1) WITH NOWAIT; -- Will raise your OnInfoMessage-method 
-- etc.

END
```

Have fun with parsing, cause remember: such messages can also be generated by the server itself (so it is probably a good idea to start your own, relevant "errors" with a satic sequence which cannot occur under nomal circumstances).

Comment: From my understanding, this example is only going to return information related to errors executing the SPROC or query? I may just be confused. This is a great post with useful information since it provides information related to feedback of errors.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Anyways there is no reason why you couldnt abuse the "error" to return progress information. For example: If you know you need execute n querys (you determined that before) you can generate one "error" at the begin which tells you that you need to execute n querys. Then you generate one "Error" after each query you executed, and so you can report progess to the client.

Comment: I would argue that anytime your verb of choice is "abuse", that solution should be put on the backburner until other solutions have been exhausted.  Not arguing that it's a *bad* solution, just that solutions that aren't described as "abuse" should be preferred.

Comment: @Amy you right, but its more a logical abuse then a technical. Severitys below 10 are classified as "Informational messages that return status information or report errors that are not severe." So they are basically made for this kind of task. Anyways i dont like it and thats why i use the term "abuse". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities

Comment: Again, I'm not arguing against doing this.  Just saying other solutions should be considered first.